# Will "full upgrade to ubuntu studio" harm unity?

Tags: desktop-environments, ubuntu-studio

I want to install ubuntu studio as a desktop alongside my unity and the other environments. What exactly does "fully upgrade" mean? Will it remove or affect unity? If yes; how? I just want to have both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Community Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu%20Studio%20Upgrade%20from%20Ubuntu),

Install the following packages:-

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-desktop ubuntustudio-audio ubuntustudio-audio-plugins ubuntustudio-graphics ubuntustudio-video
```

And You can use both flavor without removing desktop and should not affect other desktop-environment.